# Comparison Operator for Structure key in C++ Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, comparator

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct segment{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    bool const operator<(const segment &o) const {
        return a < o.a;
    }
};


int main()
{
    map<segment,int> myMap;
    map<segment,int>::iterator it;
    struct segment x,y,z;

    x.a=2;
    x.b=4;
    x.c=6;

    y.a=2;
    y.b=5;
    y.c=8;

    z.a=2;
    z.b=4;
    z.c=6;        

    myMap[y]++;
    myMap[z]++;
    myMap[x]++;

    for( it =myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
        cout<<(*it).first.a<<" "<<(*it).second<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it gives result as

```
2 3
```

but i want it to print

```
2 1
2 2
```

In short I want to increment the value of the map if exactly the same struct instance is fed instead of making a new copy

Comment: Then you have to change the less operator and compare all members.

Comment: I didn't get what you said. Can you please give the code for the comparator.

Comment: I tried a nested if else statement but it didn't work correctly

Comment: You shouldn't be including `bits/stdc++.h`, which is an implementation header. Include `map` and `iostream` instead.

Answer (score 6):

IMO the best way to compare multiple members is using `std::tie` as it is much harder to mess up:

```
bool const operator<(const segment &o) const {
    return std::tie(a, b, c) < std::tie(o.a, o.b, o.c);
}
```

**Edit:** Would just like to add this link to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) as the example there is almost exactly your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your `map` is concerned, there is only one unique object here. In terms of the comparison you specified, and the implied equivalence, `x == y` and `y == z`. Why? Neither of them is smaller than the other, so, according to STL logic by comparison, they must be equivalent.

Perhaps you're looking for a [`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/).

Alternatively, if you want to define inequality (and hence implied equivalence) in terms of all the members, you could do something like this:

```
#include <tuple>

bool const operator<(const segment &o) const {
    return std::make_tuple(a, b, c) < std::make_tuple(o.a, o.b, o.c);
}
```

---

P.S. You should avoid including stuff from `bits`, as you're including stuff from the implementation. Instead, try to use stuff like

```
// See? no bits.
#include <map>
```

Comment: I want to increment the value of the map if the same key is entered again. and for the keys to be equal I want a==o.a, b==o.b, c==o.c. Can I achieve this on map ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your less operator to:

```
bool const operator<(const segment &o) const {
    return a < o.a || (a == o.a && b < o.b) || (a==o.a && b==o.b && c < o.c) ;
}
```

This compares the values in the order of a, b, c.

But you can change it anyway you want to compare the structure.